# Does Python have a way to repeat a given number of times without explicitly assigning a counter variable?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I occasionally find myself writing

```
for i in range(n):
 stuff_that_does_not_involve_i
```

Is there some better way to do that; perhaps something along resembling

```
do n times:
 whatever
```

?

(Note that the second code fragment is not valid Python.)

Comment: I've never used Ruby.

Comment: Heh, you accidentally wrote the Ruby idiom almost word for word... (`n.times { whatever }`)

Comment: Anyway, what would be the motivation? In my opinion, `_` looks more weird than plain `i` or `n` or even `not_used_counter`. Why whould you accept the `_`? For people familiar with Perl but not familiar with Python, it may be more confusing than plain `i`. *Use whatever name you feel is appropriate.* The for-loop construct need not know whether the variable is to be used or not in the body. Nor the programmer needs to know now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, if you don't care what the loop variable's value is, name it `_`.

So:

```
for _ in range(n):
  stuff
```

Comment: Notice that in Python 2 I would probably use xrange instead, to avoid creating a completely useless list.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Definitely true, though the poster specified the python-3.x tag, and `range` is the new name for `xrange` there.

Comment: @RickyDemer In the doc: ``identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*`` . So the undescore alone constitutes an identifier as any other combination of authorized characters. Using it in a for loop doesn't change anything to the fact that a decrement or increment is repeatedly assigned to this identifier.

Comment: You should know that this has the *potential* of being a memory hole. The convention of using `_` for the target of something you don't care about is pernicious. Suppose you do `for _ in range(1000000): ...` the useless list 1 million elements long is assigned to `_` and remains until `_` is assigned as a label to something else. IMHO, it is actually *better* to use `i` as a convention for a loop variable.

Comment: @dawg There is no difference between `_` and `i` here, and neither of them gets assigned the useless list - either way, they would only hold onto the last value from the range that was encountered, and only until the end of the function. Nevermind the fact that in Python 3 (which is what's being asked about) `range` does not produce a list.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use a for-loop for that kind of functionality.

However, if you don't plan to use the counter variable in the loop body, then you should replace it with an underscore:

```
>>> for _ in range(10):
...     print('hi')
...
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
>>>
```

This, by convention, means that you will not be using the counter variable in the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use an underscore to indicate the iterator value is unused or unimportant. Additionally, if the number of times something is repeated is large, or there is a high probability of a `break` statement being called, then use an iterator instead:

```
for _ in xrange(100):
    pass # this block repeated 100 times
```

The advantage of using an iterator like `xrange` is that no array is created, so it conserves memory.

Note that on most systems/distributions, Python's `xrange` has a maximum count of 2147483647 (which is 2 ^ 31 - 1). If you need to iterate more times than that, you can wrap your own:

```
def longxrange(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1

for _ in longxrange(10000000000):
    pass # this block repeated 10,000,000,000 times
```